# cout/cin not working properly in VS code only

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++14

I'm having a problem specifically with VS code where cout and cin are not working in c++ as expected.

The program is somehow terminating after the first cout and the debugger shows "paused on exception" and then "segmentation fault".

Since the same program is running perfectly in Apache Netbeans and other online compilers, I don't think cin.ignore() or endl or anything like that is required.

C programs run perfectly fine though (in VS).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int l,b;
    cout << "\n\nENTER L and B : ";
    cin >> l >> b;
    cout << "L and B entered are : " << l << "\t" << b;    
}
```

code + output image

[image]

Here is the debugger screen image

[image]

Even simple one variable cin statement isn't running and the program is terminating automatically. [cin ain't executing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21YI9.png)

cout with any variable or constant ain't running correctly either.

simple cout image

[image]

My guess is something's wrong with memory allocation by VS code.

Comment: The code is perfectly fine. Your VS Code installation an/or compiler installation and/or VS Code settings are broken and given available information it is impossible to tell how or why.

Comment: Should I remove VS code and Mingw completely and then reinstall them?

Comment: Yup, there was some problem with the mingw.exe. I followed the official instructions on VS code website and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to ba a problem with your Compiler installation.

Consider checking the compiler installation steps from the [VS code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw).